# How to get dataset from XMLType in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

How does one extract a dataset from a set of xml documents stored in rows, as an SQL select statement? Here is a sample task that illustrates the question.

### Input

```
create table circle
  ( id       number         not null primary key
  , name_xml varchar2(2000) 
  )
/

insert into circle
 select 1, '<t><person><firstn>Sean       </firstn> <lastn>Durkin     </lastn></person>' ||
              '<person><firstn>Tom        </firstn> <lastn>Sawyr      </lastn></person></t>' from dual union all
 select 2, '<t><person><firstn>Philip     </firstn> <lastn>Marlowe    </lastn></person>' ||
              '<person><firstn>John       </firstn> <lastn>Wayne      </lastn></person>' ||
              '<person><firstn>Constantine</firstn> <lastn>Palaeologus</lastn></person></t>' from dual union all
 select 3, null from dual;
```

So in table circle, we have 5 people spread across 3 table rows. Each person is identified by a first name (`firstn`) and a last name (`lastn`).

### Input structure

The `name_xml` column is either empty or an XML documetn with root element `<t>`. Under `<t>` is any number of `<person>`. And under `<person>` is both `<firstn>` and `<lastn>` in that order. The spaces shown in the listing are just for readability and not in the real data.

### Expected output

We want to get the list of full names. It should be a single string column. From the above data we expect output ...

```
People
----------------------- 
Sean Durkin
Tom Sawyr
Philip Marlowe
John Wayne
Constantine Palaeologus
```

### Environment

My database engine is `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi`.

### What I have tried so far

From what I have read and understood, this query should work ...

```
select extract( name_parts, '/person/firstn') || ' ' || 
       extract( name_parts, '/person/firstl') as People
 from (
 select
  extract( XMLType( name_xml), '/t/person').getStringVal() as name_parts
  from circle
  where name_xml is not null)
```

But this returns error `inconsistent data type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
11:28:27 SYSTEM@dwal> l
  1  select
  2   trim(extractvalue( value(t), '/person/firstn')) ||' '||
  3   trim(extractvalue( value(t), '/person/lastn')) as people
  4  from circle
  5  ,table(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(name_xml), '/t/person'))) t
  6* where name_xml is not null
11:28:28 SYSTEM@dwal> /

PEOPLE
----------------------------------------
Sean Durkin
Tom Sawyr
Philip Marlowe
John Wayne
Constantine Palaeologus

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Or even simplier using XMLTable

```
11:36:47 SYSTEM> l
  1  select
  2    t.fname, t.lname
  3   from circle
  4   ,xmltable('/t/person'
  5    passing xmltype(circle.name_xml)
  6    columns
  7     fname varchar2(20) path '/person/firstn',
  8     lname varchar2(20) path '/person/lastn'
  9  ) t
 10*  where name_xml is not null
11:36:56 SYSTEM> /

FNAME                LNAME
-------------------- --------------------
Sean                 Durkin
Tom                  Sawyr
Philip               Marlowe
John                 Wayne
Constantine          Palaeologus

Elapsed: 00:00:00.12
11:36:58 SYSTEM> @ver

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```